# How to convert JPG to PNG on upload in WordPress (via add_image_size)?

Tags: php, wordpress, image, image-processing, imagecreatefromjpg

I asked this some days ago already [over here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/377018/how-to-convert-jpg-to-png-on-upload-via-add-image-size) at wordpress.stackexchange.com but didn't get any response since – so I thought it would be legit to ask over here again:

I am looking for a way to have one of the additional images sizes saved as PNG. Ideally the PNG-Version would be rendered on upload and defined through add_image_size.

So far I have only found one WP-plugin that has the built in capability of converting JPGs to PNGs ([EWWW Image Optimizer](https://de.wordpress.org/plugins/ewww-image-optimizer/)) but it does not really provide the functionality I'm looking for.

I know this should be possible through the PHP function imagecreatefromjpeg – but currently I just don't know where / how to hook that into add_image_size or wherever taht should be hooked in.

I hope somebody has done this before? Any pointers / suggestion appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: `add_image_size` just changes the configuration regarding your image sizes, that’s not the correct point to hook into here. You should look into hooks like `wp_handle_upload` or `wp_generate_attachment_metadata`.

Comment: Look at this topic for starter - https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/307733/convert-all-images-to-png-on-file-upload